# Checking validity of NxN Sudoku

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sudoku

Given a multi-dimensional array representing a board in Sudoku, the function should be able to return whether the sudoku is valid or not.

Examples:

```
var goodSudoku = [
  [7,8,4, 1,5,9, 3,2,6],
  [5,3,9, 6,7,2, 8,4,1],
  [6,1,2, 4,3,8, 7,5,9],

  [9,2,8, 7,1,5, 4,6,3],
  [3,5,7, 8,4,6, 1,9,2],
  [4,6,1, 9,2,3, 5,8,7],

  [8,7,6, 3,9,4, 2,1,5],
  [2,4,3, 5,6,1, 9,7,8],
  [1,9,5, 2,8,7, 6,3,4]
];

var badSudoku = [
  [1,1,1, 1,1,1,  2,2,2],
  [5,3,9, 6,7,2, 8,4,1],
  [6,1,2, 4,3,8, 7,5,9],

  [9,2,8, 7,1,5, 4,6,3],
  [3,5,7, 8,4,6, 1,9,2],
  [4,6,1, 9,2,3, 5,8,7],

  [8,7,6, 3,9,4, 2,1,5],
  [2,4,3, 5,6,1, 9,7,8],
  [1,9,5, 2,8,7, 6,3,4]
];

validSudoku(badSudoku); // false;
validSudoku(goodSudoku); // true;
```

Specific questions

- How can I improve my function? What am I doing bad/good?
- Is my algorithm efficient? Advice on it?

Here is my code

```
function validSudoku(data) {
    var valid = true, 
        temp = [], 
        data,
        side,
        slot;


    // Check wrong size
    if (data[0].length !== data.length) valid = false;

    // slot*slot
    slot = Math.sqrt(data.length);

    // Verifiy horizontal
    data.forEach(function(arr) {
        valid = valid && arr.every(function(val, i) { return arr.indexOf(i + 1) > -1; });
    });

    // Verifiy vertical lines
    data.forEach(function(arr, i) {
        temp  = data.map(function(val) { return val[i]; });
        valid = valid && arr.every(function(val, i) { return temp.indexOf(i + 1) > -1; });
    });

    // Verifiy boxes
    for (var i = 0; i < slot; i++) {

        data.forEach(function(val, e) {
            side  = val.slice(slot * i, slot * i + slot);
            temp  = temp.concat(side);

            if ((e+1) % slot == 0 && e > 0) {
                for (var j = 1; j <= data.length; j++)
                    if (temp.indexOf(j) < 0) valid = false;                 
                temp = [];
            }

        });

    }
    return valid;
}
```

Comment: You can greatly simplify by summing the value of all the rows. For a 9*9 sudoku, you would have a total of 45 on each column and line. you sum them all and you are good to go! If the sum is different, just return `false` in the middle. If you finish the loop, return `true`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel What good is summing?  If you fill the entire board with nothing but 5s, all rows and columns will also sum to 45.

Comment: @JamesMontagne You are right. My bad. I should go back to math...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few problems with your validation, and the code itself could be a bit neater.

First up, your code will try to validate impossible puzzles. Sudoku puzzles need to be square-sided You check that the puzzle is square, but your slot-size is not valid. It assumes a side that is a perfect square (4, 9, 16, etc.).

Additionally, you only check the first row is the right length, I suspect your code will validate as true if one of the rows has an extra element (with a carefully-chosen value).

In multiple places you set `valid = false`, and in those places you should just `return false`. You know the puzzle is not valid, so why continue checking?

Finally, it would be nice if you could make the checking generic. There are 3 things to check:

1. all expected elements in each row are present
2. all expected elements in each column are present
3. all expected elements in each mini-square are present.

I would try to put that together as a collection of functions for each check:

```
var extractions = [
    {   name: "rows",
        get:  function(data,span,block,member){
                  return data[block][member];
              }
    },
    {   name: "cols",
        get:  function(data,span,block,member) {
                  return data[member][block];
              }
    },
    {   name: "minis",
        get:  function(data,span,block,member) {
                  var coloff = (block % span) * span;
                  var rowoff = (block / span) * span;
                  return data[rowoff + (member / span)][coloff + (member % span)];
              }
    },
]

function isvalid(data) {
    var size = data.length;
    var slot = Math.sqrt(size);
    for (var block = 0; block < size; block++) {
        if (data[block].length != size) {
            return false;
        }
        for (var ext = 0; ext < extractions.length; ext++) {
            var tmp = [];
            for (var member = 0; member < size; member++) {
                tmp.push(extractions[ext].get(data, slot, block, member));
            }
            for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
                if (tmp.indexOf(i) < 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You have a little typo on `extractions[e]`, there is no *e* variable (I suppose it's *ext*). Thanks for the advices.

Comment: You're welcome, and fixed, and the code is completely untested..... just a suggestion ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Checking that the board's square is pretty simple:

```
function isSquare(board) {
  return board.every(function (row) {
    return row.length === board.length;
  });
}
```

You'll might still want to check that its sides are themselves perfect squares. E.g. a 7x7 sudoku board is hard to divide into boxes. I'll leave that up to you though.

To check the rows and columns, I'd suggest adding a `transpose` function, just to make things easier. It'll "flip" the board from an array or rows to an array of columns, like so:

```
function transpose(board) {
  return board.map(function (_, index) {
    return board.map(function (row) {
      return row[index];
    });
  });
}
```

And to find the boxes, here's a fairly naïve implementation (note that it assumes the sides are perfect squares):

```
function boxes(board) {
  var size = Math.sqrt(board.length),
      boxes = [];

  for(var r = 0, rl = board.length ; r < rl ; r++) {
    var row = board[r];
    for(var c = 0, cl = row.length ; c < cl ; c++) {
      var box = (r / size | 0) * size + (c / size | 0);
      boxes[box] || (boxes[box] = []);
      boxes[box].push(row[c]);
    }
  }

  return boxes;
}
```

With that you can write three simple functions:

```
function validateRows(board) {
  return board.every(isSequential);
}

function validateColumns(board) {
  return transpose(board).every(isSequential);
}

function validateBoxes(board) {
  return boxes(board).every(isSequential);
}
```

Now, as for that `isSequential` function. Here's one way to go about it: Sort the "group" (row, column, or box) in ascending order, and loop through it to check that it's sequential, starting at 1:

```
function isSequential(group) {
  var sorted = group.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  for(var i = 0, l = sorted.length ; i < l ; i++) {
    if(sorted[i] !== i + 1) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

I'm slicing the group to get a copy, because `sort` modifies the array it's called on, so it'd modify the board itself, and we don't want that. I'm also supplying a comparison callback, because the default comparator is lexicographic (i.e. it'll sort `[1, 2, 10]` as `[1, 10, 2]`).

*However*, there's also a "clever" way, using some bitwise operations:

```
function isSequential(group) {
  var sum = group.reduce(function (sum, digit) {
    return sum | 1 << (digit - 1);
  }, 0);

  return sum === (1 << group.length) - 1;
}
```

What's happening here is that each digit sets a bit in the `sum`. A 1 will set the 1st (least significant) bit, a 2 will set the 2nd bit and so on.

So, taking the first row of the `goodSudoku`, here's what happens:

```
Digit | Sum (in binary)
-------------------------
7     | 001000000
8     | 011000000
4     | 011001000
1     | 011001001
5     | 011011001
... and so on
```

If all the digits 1-9 are present in the row/column/box, the `sum` should be `111111111` (nine 1s) in binary. And that just happens to be equal to \$2^9 - 1\$. This will work as long as no digit goes above 30 (since JS bitwise operations treat stuff as signed 32-bit integers). So it's not quite NxN, but it'll work up to 30x30.

Regardless of which implementation you pick, you end up with something like:

```
function validSudoku(board) {
  return isSquare(board) && validateRows(board) && validateColumns(board) && validateBoxes(board);
}
```

Comment: The assumption is definitely false. You can have all numbers in all rows and columns while having many duplicates in the mini-boxes. For example put 123456789 in the first row, then shift by 1 until the last row. Another way to look at this is that the mini-box rule won't be there if the rules on rows and columns are sufficient.

Comment: @justhalf D'oh! Of course you're right. I shouldn't try to be clever when I'm tired. I'll fix the answer. Thanks for the correction!